# Rails environment config: `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle, actionmailer

Attempting to invoke a Rails console (`bundle exec rails c`) or Rails server (`bundle exec rails s`) causes the following exception to be thrown:

```
~/project/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdbe46e7400> (NoMethodError)
    from ~/project/config/environments/development.rb:43:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from ~/project/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from ~/project/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from ~/project/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from ~/project/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
...
```

Am I missing something here or there any other gems that could be causing an incompatibility issue?

This is the offending line in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  # Save emails to files instead of delivering.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
```

The following is the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'activemodel'
gem 'actionmailer'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'oj'
gem 'dalli-elasticache'
gem 'config'

# Frontend
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Deploy
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
gem 'capistrano-rails-log'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'vcr'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

Comment: Was it working before or did it never worked?

Comment: It never worked. This is the first time I'm attempting to use and configure actionmailer.

Comment: try remaining actionmailer from your gemfile then bundle install

Comment: That made no difference, even after reinstalling all the gems from scratch.

Comment: Does it work without `bundle exec`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `bin/rails c` produces exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution was to add:

`require 'action_mailer/railtie'`

to `config/application.rb`, as that file was not doing `require 'rails/all`.

Comment: I am facing the same error, but I'm getting this new error once I add that line:
`cannot load such file -- action_mailer/railtie (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so, I answer here
I go this error inside Docker container I added following in Dockerfile so it works for me
    `RUN BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem during the migration of Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.1. The problem was that I had different version of "Railties" gem installed.

So to solve this, after I upgraded `gem 'rails'` version to `6.1`, I also upgraded `gem 'railties'` to `6.1` too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (same first line with method_missing) but my issue had a much more prosaic explanation:

For some reason, after I'd switched around/updated my dependencies I had to remove the line

config.action_mailbox.ingress = :relay

from *both* development and production enviornments.

I'm just including the answer here so anyone else who spends hours trying to fix this finds a potential fix in the result.